# JavaScript ajax alert on post not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to post json to an api. As well as get  get html form data and convert it to json. But i cant make a simple ajax post and then   return an alert box.
What is wrong with this?`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test url",
            data: "hahaaha",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){alert(data);},
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>`
```

Comment: well submit buttons submit, cancel the submit

Comment: have you tried viewing the console for possible errors?

Comment: yes no errors and i also try to do console.log() i get nothing

Comment: Also, there's no **failure** function on the jQuery AJAX documentation, are you perhaps referring to **error**?

Comment: the button type="button" not  submit

Comment: can you post your html.

Comment: Thanks Debet  reply to it and ill mark it as best answer i changed it to error and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no failure function on the jQuery AJAX documentation, are you perhaps referring to error?